# How many people might have been involved in the design of the Macintosh SE?

Tags: design, cpu, computers

It is really difficult for me to know how many people were in charge of the development of this electronic wonder. When I'm struggling to properly comprehend transistors and how they work, these people already made this computer and nowadays there are people that create this tiny computers, laptops, cellphones (ARM), wi-fi routers, supercomputers, iphones, etc.

- How do computer engineers and computers scientists (programmers) work together?
- How do they interact with each other to accomplish their tasks?
- What "special" abilities do they have to understand this maze of integrated circuits?
- Are they some sort of "geniuses"?
- Is it necessary to be some sort of child prodigy that built 8 bit computers at age 6?
- Is it perhaps necessary to have some extraordinary "abstraction abilities" to work as a computer engineer?
- Have you guys at some point felt "fear" of not being able to comprehend computers? or perhaps overwhelmed?
  Thanks in advance for your answers!

Comment: Calm down. That project would have had enormous amounts of resources dedicated to it, and team of experienced people. There is no such thing as a child prodigy in the world of science and engineering.

Comment: This isn't a bad question, necessarily, but it's not a good fit for the site because 1) It is asking multiple questions; 2) Some of these questions require speculation or opinion; 3) It is a survey ("Have you felt...")

Comment: http://www.folklore.org/ is a blog about the history of the macintosh development, but your question seems to be more about how computer engineering and electronics engineering works generally.

Comment: @JYelton I agree. This is an odd one.  While many of the questions are basically the same, I don't know if it is "close-worthy" bad.  It seems to be looking at engineering from some what of a managerial standpoint.

Comment: @Funky It isn't really *answerable.* Even the title question, "How many people..." isn't well-defined. Does it mean people in the employ of Apple Computer? Does it include people who worked on precursors to the SE? Does it include outside engineers? Third-party manufacturers and designers? Does it include the myriad of engineers responsible for components that came before the SE, making it possible? Unfortunately it is open-ended, but even if it weren't, of what use is knowing "42 people worked on it"?

Comment: @JYelton This is true, the title isn't a good fit.  It doesn't really tie into the question at all either.  The question(s) is more on topic than the title.  But even then...it has some useful questions related to management I feel.  Maybe the title could be changed to "How do EE work with Computer Scientists?"  or something along those lines

Answer (score 2):

**Abstraction** is the idea of encapsulating complexity into a "black box" which can be utilized by only knowing its defined properties, not its inner workings.  This lets someone design a "computer" without needing to know all the details of how each "chip" works, how the power supply or monitor works, etc, but rather only needing to select or contract components which meet specifications for their externally visible behavior.

Of course real life is never this clean; Engineers are curious people and tend to have a fair idea of what goes on inside many of these black boxes.  This can be useful, as they may not perform exactly as they are specified to, and we're not above cracking the covers and looking inside to understand why.  So ultimately abstraction is not an absolute, but rather a **strategy** of knowing *everything* about the abstraction level at which you are working, and *something* about those above and below, with a *readiness to immediately learn more* if it appears that such knowledge will be needed to get the overall system working.  So you may be designing the motherboard, but if you suspect a bug in the processor, you write code to test that, or if you suspect the power supply is unreliable, you might take it apart and see if it looks poorly made inside.

This idea applies to software components, mechanical components, etc every bit as much as it does to the circuitry - overall, they must fit together to form a complete system.

As for coordination between engineering teems, precise paper (and now electronic documentation) is the textbook answer, but often the key details are written on the back of pizza-grease-stained napkins or merely shouted bench to bench ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Dude, relax.

You don't need to be a prodigy to be an accomplished engineer.  It'd be helpful but it isn't what is going to make you a star.  Remember hard work pays off more than raw talent.  The greatest items in history had few what you would call prodigies working on them, if any.

Computer scientists and engineers work together through various methods, whether it be numerous meetings or through other means.  It depends greatly on how the company is structured.  Hypothetically speaking, if they are a consulting firm, a client may need something more software oriented, and in that case, the computer scientists may run the show.  In other cases, the client may need a computer capable of doing a certain task as efficient as possible, which the engineers would run the show for that.

Naturally a computer scientist will eventually want to know more about what the engineers do and vice versa because we come from the same breed of people, so to speak. Because of that, we can usually understand each other...for the most part.

You might want to look into "Agile development" and other methods of CS development.

The thing about engineering is, yea it is complicated, but if its been done by somebody else, why not you?  There isn't really anything to fear except failure (and mains voltage) which can be avoided by hard work.